# python drop down menu attached to the windows taskbar

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working on a timer application on python 3, basically is for you to keep track of how many time spend doing something. I'm in the part of the process where i need to create an interface probably with tkinter, with a drop down menu that lists all the things i need to keep track of (lets call those things "statuses").

Now, my question is, is there a way to add that the drop down menu with the statuses in the task bar on windows? so that a user does not have to go the interface and change status, but most importantly, the current status can be always on sight.

Is this even possible? If it is, I just need a few hints please! :)

Comment: Maybe a taskbar icon?  I'm sure tkinter has a class for those.

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure about adding a drop down menu to the taskbar icon(like the one you get with Microsoft lync taskbar icon to change status, hope u need something like this), but i would suggest(incase this helps) to add menu at right click over the taskbar icon.

wxPython might help.

see this article.
http://codeboje.de/MailSneaker-Part-3-SystemTrayTaskBar-Icons-with-Python-and-wxPython/

Hope this helps.